# Trying to install a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, terminal

Trying to get this to work: http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/

I have never worked with node.js nor terminal before and could really use help..THANKS!!!

I followed the steps and I get this error :/

```
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/autosave
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/autosave
    npm ERR! Could not create /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___autosave.npm
    npm ERR! error installing autosave@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Error: EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___autosave.npm'
    npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
    npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    npm ERR! or email it to:
    npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! System Darwin 11.1.0
    npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "autosave"
    npm ERR! cwd /Users/kangaroobin
    npm ERR! node -v v0.6.6
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-4
    npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/___autosave.npm
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! message EACCES, permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/___autosave.npm'
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/kangaroobin/npm-debug.log
    npm not ok
```

This is way out of my league, I really appreciate your help, and I need some pretty detailed steps on what I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this: `sudo npm install -g autosave`. I ran into the same problem as you, tried my solution, and it works!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Now I am getting an error through the extension that says URL (file://macintosh%20hd...it gets cut off) doesn't match RegExp /^file:VV(?localhost)?V/ this gets cut off too

Answer (score 0):

You should probably re-try your `npm install` command as the `root` user; prepend `sudo` to your command and try again.

Your regular user account won't have permissions to modify content in `/usr/local` by default. It would probably be a mistake to configure permissions to try to allow your regular user account to modify content in `/usr/local`.

Comment: How do I become the root user?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Now I am getting an error through the extension that says URL (file://macintosh%20hd...it gets cut off) doesn't match RegExp /^file:VV(?localhost)?V/ this gets cut off too

Comment: "could not connect" here is what I changed from: file://macintosh%20hd/Users/kangaroobin/Local/reubenandhunter/index.html to: http://localhost/macintosh%20hd/Users/kangaroobin/Local/reubenandhunter/index.html

Comment: Not sure I understand.. Here is the guide I am using, it provides little details: http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools If I can't give it the full path, how do I pull the page up in the browser? Quite confused..sorry!

Comment: Ha! You were right, it should go through `file://`. I should have read the guide more closely the first time through. Sorry. :)